# Show text in a LineEdit C++ Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt-designer, qlineedit

I have two windows in Qt Designer, and I want to open a file .txt with text. This code belongs to the second window (pacientes.ui)

[image: pacientes.ui]

and I want to show in the first window (ventana.ui) three line of text in three LineEdit (the file .txt it has three lines of text).

[image: Mainwindow]

```
pacientes::pacientes(QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::pacientes)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
QDir path("C:/Users/Jaime/Desktop/interfaz/pacientes");
QStringList files = path.entryList(QDir::Files);

QComboBox comb;
qDebug()<<files;

ui->pacienteLista->addItems(files);
connect(this, SIGNAL( customSignalSetText(QString)), /*How I can put the variable?*/, SLOT(      customSlotSetText(QString)) ); 
}


pacientes::~pacientes()
{
   delete ui;
}
```

Venatana1 and Pacientes are defined in QtDesigner

How can I solve the mistake?

Comment: Have you set object name of your QLineEdit in designer correctly? Can you recheck that?

Comment: It seems, that that 3 lineEdits belong to another `ui` (`ventana` in your terms). You should give a reference to first window to the second window and access first window members like that `first_window_ref->ui->nameEsit-> ...`

Comment: `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '->'`

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
ui->nameEdit->setText(texto); //here it is the problem
ui->diagEdit->setText(names);
ui->dateEdit->setDate(fechas);
```

in the first window (ventana), but now you're calling it inside pacientes. So you have to send the path to the file from the pacientes to ventana and set the text in ventana.

In pacientes you should have something like this:

```
void pacientes::on_pacienteAceptar_clicked()
{
    QString pathToDirectory = "C://Users//Jaime//Desktop//interfaz//pacientes";
    QString currentFileName = ui->pacienteLista->currentText();
    QString pathToFile = QString("%1//%2").arg(pathToDirectory, currentFileName);
    emit customSignalSetText( pathToFile );
}
```

In ventana you make a custom slot that does all the work:

```
void ventana::customSlotSetText( QString const & text )
{
    if(!text.isEmpty())
    {
        QFile file(text);
        ...
    }
}
```

And in your application where you have pacientes and ventana, you connect your custom signal from pacientes to your custom slot in ventana.

EDIT:
This signal-slot connect must happen in a place where you have access to an instance of pacientes and an instance of ventana.

EDIT2:
The `connect` must also happen within a `QObject`.

```
int main(...)
{
    ...
    ventana1 w;
    w.show();
    pacientes pacientesObj(w);
    ...
}
```

In the constructor of `pacientes`:

```
pacientes::pacientes( ventana1 receiver, QWidget* parent )
{
    ...
    connect( this, SIGNAL( customSignalSetText( QString ) ), &receiver, SLOT( customSlotSetText( QString ) ) );
}
```

Note that you can not connect signals and slots between classes, only between instances of those classes.

As for emitting the signal, look [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html). It is probably one of the following: (1) you did not use the `Q_OBJECT` macro or (2) you did not declare the signal correctly (with `signals:`). If it was the first, you'll have to run `qmake` again.

Comment: It must be like...`connect(ui->pacienteAceptar, SIGNAL( pathToFile), this, SLOT( customSlotSetText(QString nombre)) ); `

Comment: `pathToFile` is not a signal, it is a `QString`.
It will be more something like: `connect(paciente, SIGNAL( customSignalSetText( QString ) ), ventana, SLOT( customSlotSetText( QString ) ) );`

Comment: ok, I have some error in the code of ventana, because the variables is from pacientes.

Comment: I had not declared the `signal:`, but the mistake of `connect` still continues. Now only I have that mistake. Q_OBJECT is being used.

Comment: I can't see what you're doing wrong if I can't see your code. Are you calling `connect` within `pacientes` like I showed in EDIT2? You can't call `connect` in the `main` function of your program.

Comment: Ok,I was calling `connect` in the `main` function. Now only I have a question, I edit again the question.

Comment: My answer already shows you this. In the constructor of `pacientes`, you have to pass an instance of `ventana`. Look carefully at my EDIT2. And if my answer helps you out, be sure to accept it as an answer :)

Comment: Show me a mistake in the line `pacientes pacientesObj(w);` `error C2664: 'pacientes::pacientes(QWidget *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ventana1' to 'QWidget *'`. Also I don't know like to do the instance.

Comment: You have to adjust your `pacientes` constructor from `pacientes::pacientes(QWidget *)` to `pacientes::pacientes(ventana1, QWidget *)`, both in the header file and the cpp file of pacientes.

Comment: in the header file I have a mistake in `explicit pacientes(ventana1,QWidget *parent = 0);` `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ventana1' 
`

Comment: `explicit pacientes(ventana1 receiver, QWidget *parent = 0)` and include your `ventana1` `.h`-file. This is just basic stuff, man.

Comment: I have the same mistake, the ventana1.h was put.